# Converting NULL to Blank in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I need some guidance with a dynamic pivoting in SQL SEVER 2012. I have been able to successfully pivot the data in the way I wanted however, in the final output, I get to see `NULL`.

**Objective**

I would like to ensure that these `NULL` values are instead shown as Blanks.

Below is an exempel of what my that looks like in the final out.

```
=========================================================
Week     Type       kawasaki    Aston Martin
=========================================================
52      Two Wheel       2             NULL
52      Four Wheel      NULL            10
```

**First attempt Code**

My main dataset is in the #temp table I use for the dynamic pivoting process. Kawasaki and Aston Martin are "Model".

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
    SELECT @ColumnName=ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
                           + QUOTENAME(Model)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Model FROM #Temp) AS Courses

    --Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
      N'SELECT Week,Type,' + @ColumnName + '
        FROM (Select Sold,Week,Type,Model from #temp) src
            PIVOT(
                    SUM(ISNULL(Sold),0) 
                      FOR Model IN (' + @ColumnName + ') ) AS PVT'
    --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query

            EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

With the above code, I made a first naive attempt using `ISNULL` in my `SUM` aggregate that does not work.

My question is, how can I convert the `NULL` to blanks?

Optional, as this question might help other people in my situation, how to convert the `NULL` to 0(Zero)?

**Final output example**:

```
=========================================================
Week     Type       kawasaki    Aston Martin
=========================================================
52      Two Wheel       2             Blank
52      Four Wheel      Blank           10
```

Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try with `REPLACE` Or `CASE`.

Comment: Try using [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190349.aspx). SUM(COALESCE(Sold, 0))

Comment: this is a presentation issue better handled by a reporting tool. does the output is handed directly to the end user? is there a presentation layer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Week, Type, ISNULL(kawasaki , 'blanks') 
   AS kawasaki , ISNULL([Aston Martin], 'blanks') AS AstonMartin
   FROM  tablename
```

Comment: I tried working on @ColumnName , which is "model", however I am not able to get it to work. Your solution is good for only two models, however if I were to have like 10 different models then it wont be a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to convert null to 0, you have the function

select NVL (column , 0)
 from table ;